# Adding tabluar data for multiple worksheets in same location without 3 for loops

Tags: excel, loops, tabular, worksheet, vba

I have a excel workbook with multiple worksheet in it. Each having a tabluar data at same position in each excel sheet with same dimension. I need to add the cell values and aggregate the values into a new worksheet. Is there any better way of doing this without 3 for loops as the number of sheets are huge and the dimension of tabular data also big.

Sheet1(I9) position

```
AA  3   4   5   4   3   0
AT  2   1   1   2   1   0
AG  0   3   1   3   1   0
AC  1   2   0   0   0   0
AY  3   3   1   2   1   0
AR  3   7   6   7   4   0
TA  1   2   0   0   5   0
```

etc.......

Sheet2(I9) position

```
AA  4   1   0   3   5   0
AT  3   6   1   0   1   0
AG  1   4   0   1   4   0
AC  2   4   3   5   4   0
AY  5   10  4   5   5   0
AR  5   5   0   4   9   0
TA  2   0   2   3   4   0
```

...............
..............
SheetN(I9) position

```
AA  43  35  27  27  28  0
AT  17  27  23  12  22  0
AG  12  16  23  18  13  0
AC  12  21  13  13  19  0
AY  29  48  36  25  41  0
AR  55  51  50  45  41  0
TA  22  19  21  17  15  0
```

Comment: Not clear for me what are your actual attempts and what is the expected result. Please read> [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

if the data is in the same cells then insert a new sheet at the front of the sheets and use sum to add up through the sheets:

```
 =Sum(sheet1:sheetN!B2) will add up all cells B2 in each sheet from sheet 1 to sheet N
```

EDIT

```
Sub demo()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = Worksheets.Add(before:=Worksheets(1))
ws.Range("I9").Formula = "=Sum(" & Worksheets(2).Name & ":" & Worksheets(Worksheets.Count).Name & "!I9)"
ws.Range("i9").Copy ws.Range("i9:p200")
```

End Sub

Comment: The sum should be I9:I200-P9:P200 . Because the table is starting at I9 and ending at P200

Comment: You can either use =SUM(sheet1:sheetN!I9:P200)  whcih will give you a single total, or use =SUM(sheet1:sheetn!I9) in the cell I9 in your new top sheet, and then copy it to the range I9:p200 to give you individual totals for each cell, depending on what you want

Comment: Then record yourself typing the formula's in Developer, Record Macro

Comment: That I did but the code is not very good to rewrite my way. Also the code coming as ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=SUM(Sheet1:Sheet88!R[-3]C[8])" , here Sheet 88 is fixed, no way I am able to make it dynamic; I meant to say how to change Sheet1:Sheet88 dynamic as Sheet1:SheetN

Comment: Ahh! you want it to sum from sheet1 to the last cell in the workbook?

Comment: yes... this can't be decided prior what will be the last sheet.. and we need to calculate for all sheet